# What's the right way to upsert all values from a CSV to a Postgres table that is referenced by other tables?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table that is referenced by multiple other tables.

I exported the table to a CSV file, updated some values, and also inserted a bunch of new rows.

Now I want the table to reflect the CSV completely.  But I don't know how to import the CSV doing an upsert of the old values and insert of the new ones.

Is there a "correct" way to do this?  I don't want to delete (disable) constraints, delete the table, create a new one, insert, and then enable constraints if there is a simpler way to go about it.

Comment: Load it to a staging table, and do your upsert from there.

Comment: You can use @Mike Organek answer. The question though is; why are you doing this in the first place? Why not do the ```UPDATE``` /```INSERT``` directly to the table using ```INSERT ... ON CONFLICT```?

Comment: I guess because I needed to move them from a `csv` file into a table first so I can then do the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [Sean Behan](https://gist.github.com/seanbehan/d8d0697d3dbe7eb90550)

```
create temporary table temp (symbol varchar(255), open decimal, high decimal, low decimal, close decimal, volume varchar(255), date date );

create table if not exists stocks (id serial primary key, symbol varchar(255), open decimal, high decimal, low decimal, close decimal, volume varchar(255), date date, created_at timestamp, updated_at timestamp);

copy temp (symbol, date, open, high, low, close, volume) from '/path/to/file.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header;

delete from stocks using temp where stocks.date = temp.date and stocks.symbol = temp.symbol;

insert into stocks (symbol, open, high, low, close, volume, date) select symbol, open, high, low, close, volume, date from temp;

drop table temp;
```