# How to convert Python operated dag in PostgreSQL operated dag?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, airflow

I have airflow dag written to work with Python operator.I need to use PostgreSQL operator for same dag without changing functionality of dag. Here is code with Python operators. How Should I replace Python operator with PostgreSQL operator? Or can we use two different operators in a single dag?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import dag
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import os 
script_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
import time
from time import sleep

from xlwt import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer
from csv import DictReader
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
import psycopg2

opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
       
wb=Workbook()
sheet1=wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1',cell_overwrite_ok=False)
i=0
j=0
default_args = {
     'owner': 'airflow',
     'retries': 1
    }

dag = DAG( 'Yahoo_Finance',
            default_args=default_args,
            description='fetching ticker symbol',
            catchup=False, 
            start_date= datetime.now(), 
            schedule_interval= '* 7 * * *'  
          )  

def extract_tickers():
  conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres', user='airflow', password='airflow', host='postgres')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  with open(r'./fromlocal/EQUITY_L.csv') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com"
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub", options=opt)
    driver.get(url)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
      time.sleep(4)
      # action = ActionChains(driver)
      time.sleep(4)

      searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('yfin-usr-qry')
      time.sleep(4)

      searchBox.send_keys(row['SYMBOL'])
      time.sleep(4)

      # clicking on search
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-desktop-search-button"]').click()
      time.sleep(15)

      companyname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1')
      ticker = companyname = str(companyname[0].text)
      print("comapny name: "+ companyname)
      ticker = ticker[::-1]
      ticker = ticker[1:ticker.find("(")]
      ticker = ticker[::-1]
      print("extracted ticker: " + ticker)
      companyname = companyname[:companyname.find(" (")]
      companyname = companyname.replace("'","''")
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO tickers1 (keyword,companyName) values ('" + ticker + "','" + companyname + "')")
      conn.commit()
    
    cur.close() 
    conn.close()

print(script_dir_path)

Yahoo_Finance = PythonOperator(task_id = 'extract_tickers', 
                              python_callable = extract_tickers, 
                              provide_context = True,
                              dag= dag )

Yahoo_Finance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostgesOperator` runs SQL. Your code is querying API, generate a CSV and loading it to the DB. You can not do that with `PostgesOperator`.

What you can do is to replace the usage of `psycopg2` with `PostgresHook`.
The hook is a wrapper around `psycopg2` that expose you functions that you can interact with. This means that, for example, you don't need to handle how to connect to Postgres on your own. Simply define the connection in `Admin -> Connections` and reference the connection name in the hook:

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook
def extract_tickers():
    with PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="postgres_default").get_conn() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("Your SQL CODE")
```

To see other methods available in the hook check the hook [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/942f8fd65799f07a01f64c855c0587ae044e55ec/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py#L35).

Comment: Thanks....That's exactly what I am looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the Tasks as follows

0. Task0 Uses the PostgresOperator and creates the Table.

```
create_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create_table',
        postgres_conn_id='airflo_db_id',
        sql="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yahoo_data_rev(id BIG serial, stock_name VARCHAR, open NUMERIC, close NUMERIC, 
high NUMERIC, low NUMERIC)"""
    )
```

1. Task1 uses the Python Operator, uses webdriver, scrapes the site and creates the CSV. That is done with Python Operator.
2. Task2 Uses the Postgres Operator as below

```
insert_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='insert_table',
        postgres_conn_id='airflo_db_id',
        sql="""COPY yahoo_data_rev from /file/path/yahoo_rev.csv
WIT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER)"""
    )
```

1. Name the Tables created above uniquely for each time the DAG runs.
2. The CSV file names have to similarly unique for each DAG run.

The tables created from this DAG can be merged with the main table that is maintained using another DAG schedule after the market hours. That DAG also will implement the PostgreSQL Operator to run the queries.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66112728/16388185
discusses how to upsert the data into existing table. You may refer to it, if you are thinking about using Upsert instead of inserting and later merging.